# exception when executing JDBC query in logstash .conf file

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

MySQL 5.6.35
RHEL 7
Logstash version 6.2.4
MySQL driver: mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar

I am getting the following error when I run my logstash script

```
[2018-06-18T14:39:49,395][WARN ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ] Exception when executing JDBC query {:exception=>#<Sequel::DatabaseError: Java::JavaLang::IllegalArgumentException: MONTH>}
[2018-06-18T14:39:49,667][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline has terminated {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x2937cfc6@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:247 run>"}
```

It is always in the same group of records, so I am sure it is a data issue.

the fact the error mentions `IllegalArgumentException: MONTH>` makes me think it is a date issue, but I can't see any obvious issues in the data, and the error message does not give me enough information to home in any further on error. all my empty dates are null rather than '0000-00-00'

Does anyone know if there are any other logs that would help me identify the error.

this is the script in my conf.d folder.

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hawk_aol"
#useCursorFetch=true&
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => ""
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/apps/elasticsearch/drivers/mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM weekly_data"
    #jdbc_fetch_size => "5000"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_page_size => 100000

    }
  }
output {
  stdout { codec => json_lines }
  elasticsearch {
  "hosts" => "localhost:9200"
  "index" => "aol"
  "document_type" => "weekly_data"
  "document_id" => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem. I thought the issue was related to dates, I had been searching in my database for dates with a value of 0000-00-00 and converting them to null, however there was one date with a value of 2016-00-00, once I cleared that to null, everything starting running as expected.